# How do I answer this navigation problem?

Tags: navigation, ppl, magnetic-variation

This question is from the PPL questions book, navigation part.

> Given: QDM: 279° VAR: 5° W DEV: 5° E
>   The QDR equals...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there are specific part you don't understand?

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong. I know that the DEV part is used to get the Magnetic Heading and what I should do is subtract 5 degrees from the given QDM but what should I do with VAR which is given. Is that about the Course Heading? Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDM is magnetic bearing *to* station, QDR is magnetic bearing *from* station so VAR and DEV are here only to confuse you; the QDR is opposite of QDM so the answer is 099.

Notice that QDR and QDM do not depend on aircraft’s heading or flight path, they are only dependent on A/Cs location relative to the station.